WebSocket connection ending and re-establishing navigation to different pages
I am building a medium sized project on React with Vite. The websocket connection gets closed and re-established when navigate to another page using the sidebar
main.tsx :-
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';
import './index.css';
import { AuthProvider } from '@/contexts/AuthContext';
import React from 'react';
import { WebSocketProvider } from '@/contexts/WebSocketContext';

const Root = React.memo(() => (
    <React.StrictMode>
        <AuthProvider>
            <WebSocketProvider>
                <App />
            </WebSocketProvider>
        </AuthProvider>
    </React.StrictMode>
));

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!).render(<Root />);

router.tsx :-
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from 'react-router-dom';
import SignInPage from '@/pages/SignInPage';
import TasksPage from '@/pages/Tasks/TasksPage';
import CreateTaskPage from '@/pages/Tasks/CreateTaskPage';
import DashboardPage from '@/pages/Dashboard/DashboardPage';
import AuthRedirect from '@/components/AuthComponents/AuthRedirect';
import ProtectedRoute from '@/components/AuthComponents/ProtectedRoute';
import TaskViewPage from '@/pages/Tasks/TaskViewPage';
import EditTaskPage from '@/pages/Tasks/EditTaskPage';
import MembersPage from '@/pages/Members/Members/MembersPage';
import CreateMemberPage from '@/pages/Members/Members/CreateMemberPage';
import MemberViewPage from '@/pages/Members/Members/MemberViewPage';
import MemberEditPage from '@/pages/Members/Members/MemberEditPage';
import MemberDashboardPage from '@/pages/Members/Dashboard/MemberDashboardPage';
import MemberActivity from '@/pages/Activity/MemberActivity';
import MyActivity from '@/pages/Activity/MyActivity';
import NotificationsPage from '@/pages/Activity/NotificationsPage';
import Alerts from '@/pages/Activity/Alerts';
import Account from '@/pages/Account/Account';
import NotFoundPage from "@/pages/404";

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <AuthRedirect />,
  },
  {
    path: 'sign-in',
    element: <SignInPage />,
  },
  {
    path: 'tasks',
    element: (
      <ProtectedRoute>
        <TasksPage />
      </ProtectedRoute>
    ),
  },
  {
    path: 'create-task',
    element: (
      <ProtectedRoute>
        <CreateTaskPage />
      </ProtectedRoute>
    ),
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    element: (
      <ProtectedRoute>
        <DashboardPage />
      </ProtectedRoute>
    ),
  },
  {
    path: 'task/:id',
    element: (
      <ProtectedRoute>
        <TaskViewPage />
      </ProtectedRoute>
    ),
  },
  {
    path: 'task/edit/:id',
    element: (
      <ProtectedRoute>
        <EditTaskPage />
      </ProtectedRoute>
    ),
  },
  {
    path: 'members',
    element: (
      <ProtectedRoute>
        <MembersPage />
      </ProtectedRoute>
    ),
  },
  {
    path: '/members/create',
    element: (
      <ProtectedRoute>
        <CreateMemberPage />
      </ProtectedRoute>
    ),
  },
  {
    path: '/member/:id',
    element: (
      <ProtectedRoute>
        <MemberViewPage />
      </ProtectedRoute>
    ),
  },
  {
    path: '/member/edit/:id',
    element: (
      <ProtectedRoute>
        <MemberEditPage />
      </ProtectedRoute>
    ),
  },
  {
    path: '/members/dashboard',
    element: (
      <ProtectedRoute>
        <MemberDashboardPage />
      </ProtectedRoute>
    ),
  },
  {
    path: '/activity/members',
    element: (
      <ProtectedRoute>
        <MemberActivity />
      </ProtectedRoute>
    ),
  },
  {
    path: '/activity/member',
    element: (
      <ProtectedRoute>
        <MyActivity />
      </ProtectedRoute>
    ),
  },
  {
    path: '/activity/notifications',
    element: (
      <ProtectedRoute>
        <NotificationsPage />
      </ProtectedRoute>
    ),
  },
  {
    path: '/activity/alerts',
    element: (
      <ProtectedRoute>
        <Alerts />
      </ProtectedRoute>
    ),
  },
  {
    path: '/account',
    element: (
      <ProtectedRoute>
        <Account />
      </ProtectedRoute>
    ),
  },
  {
    path: "*",
    element: (
      <ProtectedRoute>
        <NotFoundPage />
      </ProtectedRoute>
    )
  }
]);

export function Router() {
  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
}

WebSocketContext.tsx :-
import React, { createContext, ReactNode, useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { getMemberId } from '@/utils/auth';
import { Notification } from '@/types/NotificationTypes';
import { nanoid } from 'nanoid';

interface WebSocketContextType {
  notifications: Notification[];
  addNotification: (newNotification: Notification) => void;
  removeNotification: (notificationId: string) => void;
}

const WebSocketContext = createContext<WebSocketContextType | undefined>(undefined);

export const WebSocketProvider: React.FC<{ children: ReactNode }> = ({ children }) => {
  const [notifications, setNotifications] = useState<Notification[]>([]);
  const userId = getMemberId();

  const addNotification = (newNotification: Notification) => {
    newNotification = { ...newNotification, id: nanoid(), vanish: true };
    setNotifications([...notifications, newNotification]);

    setTimeout(() => {
      removeNotification(newNotification.id ?? '');
    }, 5000);
  };

  const removeNotification = (notificationId: string) => {
    setNotifications((notifications) =>
      notifications.filter((notification) => notification.id !== notificationId)
    );
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!userId) {
      console.error('User ID is not available.');
      return;
    }

    const socket = new WebSocket(`wss://apiuverp.stepnex.tech/notifications/ws/${userId}`);

    socket.onopen = () => {
      console.log('WebSocket connection established');
    };

    socket.onmessage = (event) => {
      try {
        const newNotification = JSON.parse(event.data);
        if (
          newNotification &&
          newNotification.description &&
          newNotification.priority &&
          newNotification.url &&
          newNotification.id
        ) {
          setNotifications((prevMessages) => [...prevMessages, newNotification]);
          const acknowledgment = {
            action: 'acknowledge',
            notificationId: newNotification.id,
            memberId: userId,
          };
          socket.send(JSON.stringify(acknowledgment));
        } else {
          console.warn('Received malformed message:', newNotification);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error parsing WebSocket message:', error);
      }
    };

    socket.onerror = (error) => {
      console.error('WebSocket error:', error);
    };

    socket.onclose = (event) => {
      console.log('WebSocket connection closed', event);
    };

    return () => {
      socket.close();
    };
  }, [userId]);

  return (
    <WebSocketContext.Provider value={{ notifications, addNotification, removeNotification }}>
      {children}
    </WebSocketContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useWebSocketMessages = () => {
  const context = useContext(WebSocketContext);
  if (context === undefined) {
    throw new Error('useWebSocketMessages must be used within a WebSocketProvider');
  }
  return context;
};

MainLayout.tsx (where i display notification) :-
'use client';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Dialog, DialogBackdrop, DialogPanel, TransitionChild } from '@headlessui/react';
import { Bars3Icon, BellIcon, UserCircleIcon, XMarkIcon } from '@heroicons/react/24/outline';
import Sidebar from '@/components/Common/Sidebar';
import MobileSidebar from '@/components/Common/MobileSidebar';
import TopBar from '@/components/Common/TopBar';
import { useWebSocketMessages } from '@/contexts/WebSocketContext';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import axiosInstance from '@/axiosInstance';
import { Notification, NotificationPriority } from '@/types/NotificationTypes';
import navigation from '@/utils/NavigationItems';
import { Scope } from '@/types/EmployeeTypes';
import NotificationDropdown from '@/components/Notification/NotificationDropdown';
import { getScope } from '@/utils/auth';
import NotificationComponent from '@/components/Notification/NotificationComponent';
import HighPriorityNotification from '@/components/Notification/HighPriorityNotification';

interface SidebarLayoutProps {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  pageName: string;
}

export default function MainLayout({ children, pageName }: SidebarLayoutProps) {
  const [sidebarOpen, setSidebarOpen] = useState(false);
  const [localNotifications, setLocalNotifications] = useState<Notification[]>([]);
  const [isDropdownOpen, setIsDropdownOpen] = useState(false);
  const { notifications, removeNotification } = useWebSocketMessages();
  const [highPriorityNotificationExists, setHighPriorityNotificationExists] =
    useState<boolean>(false);

  const userScope = getScope();

  const handleNotificationIconClick = () => {
    setIsDropdownOpen(!isDropdownOpen);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setLocalNotifications(notifications);
  }, [notifications]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (notifications.length > 0) {
      const latestMessage = notifications[notifications.length - 1];
      console.log('New notification:', latestMessage);
      setLocalNotifications((prevNotifications) => [...prevNotifications, latestMessage]);
    }
  }, [notifications]);

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchTasksWithDeadlines = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axiosInstance.get('/tasks/dead_task'); // Replace with your API endpoint

        if (typeof response.data === 'string' && response.data !== 'null') {
          navigate(`/task/${response.data}`);
        } else if (response.data === null) {
          return;
        } else {
          console.error('Unexpected response format');
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching tasks:', error);
      }
    };

    fetchTasksWithDeadlines();
  }, [navigate]);

  return (
    <div className={'antialiasing'}>
      <div className={'h-full bg-gray-400'}>
        <div className={'z-50 text-black'}>
          <Dialog open={sidebarOpen} onClose={setSidebarOpen} className="relative z-50 lg:hidden">
            <DialogBackdrop
              transition
              className="fixed inset-0 bg-gray-900/80 transition-opacity duration-300 ease-linear data-[closed]:opacity-0"
            />

            <div className="fixed inset-0 flex">
              <DialogPanel
                transition
                className="relative mr-16 flex w-full max-w-xs flex-1 transform transition duration-300 ease-in-out data-[closed]:-translate-x-full"
              >
                <TransitionChild>
                  <div className="absolute left-full top-0 flex w-16 justify-center pt-5 duration-300 ease-in-out data-[closed]:opacity-0">
                    <button
                      type="button"
                      onClick={() => setSidebarOpen(false)}
                      className="-m-2.5 p-2.5"
                    >
                      <span className="sr-only">Close sidebar</span>
                      <XMarkIcon aria-hidden="true" className="h-6 w-6 text-white" />
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </TransitionChild>
                {/* Sidebar component, swap this element with another sidebar if you like */}
                <MobileSidebar Navigation={navigation} />
              </DialogPanel>
            </div>
          </Dialog>
          <TopBar pageName={pageName} />
        </div>

        {/* Static sidebar for desktop */}
        <div className="hidden lg:fixed lg:inset-y-0 lg:z-50 lg:flex lg:w-72 lg:flex-col">
          {/* Sidebar component, swap this element with another sidebar if you like */}
          <Sidebar />
        </div>

        <div className="sticky top-0 z-40 flex items-center gap-x-6 bg-white px-4 py-4 shadow-sm sm:px-6 lg:hidden">
          <button
            type="button"
            onClick={() => setSidebarOpen(true)}
            className="-m-2.5 p-2.5 text-gray-700 lg:hidden"
          >
            <span className="sr-only">Open sidebar</span>
            <Bars3Icon aria-hidden="true" className="h-6 w-6" />
          </button>
          <h2 className={'flex flex-row flex-grow'}>{pageName}</h2>
          {userScope !== Scope.EM && (
            <div>
              <span className="inline-flex items-center rounded-md bg-custom-blue-1 px-2 py-1 text-lg font-medium text-custom-blue-2 ring-1 ring-inset ring-blue-700/10">
                Admin
              </span>
            </div>
          )}
          <div className={'ml-10 flex flex-row justify-end gap-8'}>
            <div className="relative">
              <div
                className="relative hover:bg-gray-100 rounded-full cursor-pointer"
                onClick={handleNotificationIconClick}
              >
                <BellIcon height={32} />
              </div>
              {isDropdownOpen && (
                <div className="absolute right-0 mt-2">
                  <NotificationDropdown />
                </div>
              )}
            </div>
            <UserCircleIcon height={32} />
          </div>
        </div>

        <main className="py-1 lg:pl-64 bg-background-grey min-h-screen relative lg:pt-16">
          <div className="px-2 sm:px-4 lg:px-8 relative flex min-h-full flex-col bg-background-grey gap-4 my-4">
            {children}
          </div>
        </main>
      </div>
      {localNotifications.length > 0 && (
        <div className="flex flex-col fixed bottom-4 z-50 w-auto gap-2 right-4">
          {notifications.map((notification, index) => {
            if (notification.priority === NotificationPriority.HIGH) {
              console.log('HIGH PRIORITY NOTIFICATION RECEIVED');
              return (
                <HighPriorityNotification
                  setHighPriorityNotificationExists={setHighPriorityNotificationExists}
                  agenda={notification.agenda}
                  description={notification.description}
                  url={notification.url}
                />
              );
            }
            return (
              <NotificationComponent
                id={notification.id}
                removeNotification={removeNotification}
                key={index}
                priority={notification.priority}
                agenda={notification.agenda}
                description={notification.description}
                success={true}
                button_name={notification.button_name}
                url={notification.url}
                created_at={notification.created_at}
              />
            );
          })}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

Sidebar.tsx :-
import { Disclosure, DisclosureButton, DisclosurePanel } from '@headlessui/react';
import { ChevronRightIcon } from '@heroicons/react/20/solid';
import { useAuth } from '@/contexts/AuthContext';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

import React from 'react';
import navigation from '@/utils/NavigationItems';

function classNames(...classes: string[]) {
  return classes.filter(Boolean).join(' ');
}

// Example of how to dynamically build the sidebar
export default function Sidebar() {
  const { logout } = useAuth();
  const location = useLocation();
  const currentPath = location.pathname;

  return (
    <div className="flex grow flex-col gap-y-5 overflow-y-auto border-r border-gray-200 bg-white px-6 py-1 h-screen fixed top-0 left-0 w-80 lg:w-64">
      <a href={'/'} className="flex h-16 shrink-0 items-center">
        <img alt="Your Company" src="/images/company_logo.png" className="h-auto w-full" />
      </a>
      <nav className="flex flex-1 flex-col">
        <ul role="list" className="flex flex-1 flex-col gap-y-7">
          <li>
            <ul role="list" className="-mx-2 space-y-1">
              {navigation.map((item) => (
                <li key={item.name}>
                  {!item.children ? (
                    <a
                      href={item.href}
                      className={classNames(
                        currentPath === item.href ? 'bg-gray-100' : 'hover:bg-gray-50',
                        'group flex gap-x-3 rounded-md p-2 text-sm font-semibold leading-6 text-gray-700'
                      )}
                    >
                      <item.icon aria-hidden="true" className="h-6 w-6 shrink-0 text-gray-400" />
                      {item.name}
                    </a>
                  ) : (
                    <Disclosure as="div">
                      <DisclosureButton
                        className={classNames(
                          currentPath.startsWith(item.href as string)
                            ? 'bg-gray-100'
                            : 'hover:bg-gray-50',
                          'group flex w-full items-center gap-x-3 rounded-md p-2 text-left text-sm font-semibold leading-6 text-gray-700'
                        )}
                      >
                        <item.icon aria-hidden="true" className="h-6 w-6 shrink-0 text-gray-400" />
                        {item.name}
                        <ChevronRightIcon
                          aria-hidden="true"
                          className="ml-auto h-5 w-5 shrink-0 text-gray-400 group-data-[open]:rotate-90 group-data-[open]:text-gray-500"
                        />
                      </DisclosureButton>
                      <DisclosurePanel as="ul" className="mt-1 px-2">
                        {item.children.map((subItem) => (
                          <li key={subItem.name}>
                            <DisclosureButton
                              as="a"
                              href={subItem.href}
                              className={classNames(
                                currentPath === subItem.href ? 'bg-gray-100' : 'hover:bg-gray-50',
                                'block rounded-md py-2 pl-9 pr-2 text-sm leading-6 text-gray-700'
                              )}
                            >
                              {subItem.name}
                            </DisclosureButton>
                          </li>
                        ))}
                      </DisclosurePanel>
                    </Disclosure>
                  )}
                </li>
              ))}
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li className="mt-auto">
            <button
              className="inline-flex w-full items-center gap-x-2 rounded-md bg-[#667A8A] px-3.5 py-2.5 text-sm font-semibold text-white shadow-sm hover:bg-[#8093A4] focus-visible:outline focus-visible:outline-2 focus-visible:outline-offset-2 focus-visible:outline-indigo-600 mb-4"
              onClick={() => logout()}
            >
              <svg
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                fill="none"
                viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                strokeWidth={2.5}
                stroke="currentColor"
                className="w-5 h-5"
              >
                <path
                  strokeLinecap="round"
                  strokeLinejoin="round"
                  d="M15.75 9V5.25A2.25 2.25 0 0013.5 3h-9a2.25 2.25 0 00-2.25 2.25v13.5A2.25 2.25 0 004.5 21h9a2.25 2.25 0 002.25-2.25V15M9 12h12m0 0l-3-3m3 3l-3 3"
                />
              </svg>
              Logout
            </button>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  );
}

I thought maybe the reason could be because i am using anchor tags in navigation instead of Link tags for navigation but even that didnt seem to work. This seems like an issue of unnecessary unmounting and remounting of WebSocketContext. Still not able to find the reason.

As soon as you introduce React Router, you should be thinking in terms of an SPA (single page application) which means you should use the Link component provided when navigating to ensure AJAX is used instead of a full page refresh (what the anchor tags will do)

In your websocket provider, the useEffect has 1 dependency: userId. Is the userId changing unexpectedly and triggering a rerender of the websocket connection code?

thanks, it works now. Using anchor tags instead of  component was the issue.

Your anchor tags are causing a full page refresh when they are clicked. Using anchor tags in this scenario breaks your single page application (SPA) because you require state to be maintained across pages (specifically the websocket connection provider).
Since you are using React Router: firstly make sure your web socket provider component is a parent of the router element to ensure it is not rerendered when the router changes content; secondly replace all anchor tags to use the <Link> react component to tell react to update only the router element with the new content. This will keep the current web socket provider state in memory without re-establishing a new connection.
In SPAs, regular anchor tags are only really used for external links outside of the state of your application.
See here: https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/link
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

